# Webapp UI package

Tags: javascript, user-interface, web-applications, web-application-design

I'm creating a single page javascript webapp. If I want to make an app like this:

[image]

What is an ui package that could get me closest there?

Comment: What specific features are you looking for?

Comment: I can't see any image here...

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Ext-JS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/). It should be possible to desing the above webpage using it. Although its basically javascript but involves a not-ignorable learning curve. Though nowadays, they provide an awsesome documentation and you can get many basic examples on the web.